# Javascript function return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've an AngularJS project and there the is a get request is made to the backend like this which will return the data and this function is used because the get request to the same url is made multiple times

```
function getfunction(some input data) {
    $http.get('requset URL' , { params : {some parameters})
    .success(function(data){
        return data;
    });
}
var output = getfunction(input data to the function);
```

However the output is always undefined how can I fix it so the output will have the values returned from the above get request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$http returns a promise. Your data will arrive asynchronously.

```
function getfunction(some input data) {
    return $http.get('requset URL' , { params : {some parameters});
}

var output;
getfunction(input data to the function).then(function(data){
  output = data;
}, function(){
  // Handle errors.
});
```

Comment: You should return the promise from function: `return $http.get(...);`. I'm not an angularjs developper but this is what it looks like, right?!

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks, I didn't see that part.

Comment: In fact, the `success()` handler within `getFunction()` might be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

`$http.get` uses [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/). Or in other words: it does the request asynchronously.

You can return what `$http.get` returns itself - a promise - and add a continuation using `then`:

```
function getfunction(some input data) {
    return $http.get('requset URL' , { params : {some parameters});
}

getfunction(input data to the function).then(function(data) {

});

// or .success

getfunction(input data to the function).success(function(data) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The call is asynchronous, so the function you are calling will run first and then the success callback will run when the response is returned from your get request. The success handler should be what handles the output in this scenario (e.g showing the return value in a textbox)

Answer (score 0):

$http return $promise. so either you use $q service :

```
function getfunction(some input data) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('requset URL' , { params : {some parameters})
    .success(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data)
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
var output = getfunction(input data to the function).then(function(data){
  output = data;
}, function(err){
  console.log(err)
});
```

or

```
function getfunction(some input data) {
  return $http.get('requset URL' , { params : {some parameters});

}

var output;
getfunction(input data to the function).then(function(data){
  output = data;
}, function(err){
  console.log(err)
});
```